# Computation of row-wise weights in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Let `X` be an array of shape `(N,D)` and let `gamma` be of shape `(N,K)`.

I now want to compute, for all `k = 0,1,2,...K-1` the weighted sum of `D`-dimensional vectors:

`s[k] = gamma[1,k]*X[1,:] + ... + gamma[N,k]*X[N,:]`

How can I do this efficiently in `numpy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be achieved by using [np.dot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html):

```
import numpy as np
N = 3
D = 5
K = 2

x = np.arange(N*D).reshape((N,D))
gamma = np.arange(N*K).reshape((N,K))

# (K,N) , (N,D) -> (K,D)
np.dot(gamma.T,x) # equivalently, np.matmul(gamma.T,x) or gamma.T @ x

>>> array([[ 50,  56,  62,  68,  74],
           [ 65,  74,  83,  92, 101]])
```

which easily verifies your summation with an explicit `for` loop:

```
for k in range(K):
    gamma[0,k]*x[0,:] + gamma[1,k]*x[1,:] + gamma[2,k]*x[2,:]
>>> array([50, 56, 62, 68, 74])
>>> array([65, 74, 83, 92, 101])
```

Alternatively, if you like Einstein summation notation you can try using [np.einsum](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
np.einsum('ji,jk', gamma, x)
```

Comment: np.dot() is just the explicit function for "@". That is, you can simply do "gamma.T @ x" instead.